# What do the HWE-Next or linux-oem packages do/mean

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, launchpad

I have a device with a RealTek rtl8821CE wifi module. It does not work well on Ubuntu 18.04 and I have been using a third party driver. However the bluetooth still does not work. While searching about this I came across the relevant launchpad bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+bug/1742613).

I wanted to know what do the specific packages where the bug is "fixed" mean. That is, the HWE Next and the linux-oem package. Does this mean I can get rid of the bluetooth issue by installing a specific kernel? Or that it is going to be solved in the next point release?

I have not been able to find a lot of information in this regard. Sorry if this seems like a stupid/repeated question.

EDIT: I meant to ask what do the HWE-Next or linux-oem packages do/mean. Are they kernel versions where the bug is fixed? In that case can I expect to get the bug fixes in the upcoming releases?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typically specific packages labeled as "Fixed" In a bug report indicate that the particular bug has been fixed on those packages and installing that particular package will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your edited question. HWE kernels provide support for newer hardware. I've had good luck with them on some newer systems. You have learn more about them [here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

The [linux-oem package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-oem) is just a meta package that has dependencies that install a [newer version of the kernel. and currently [include updated firmware and microcode.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-image-oem)

You can find out a great deal about packages in future by simply utilizing [Ubuntu Packages Search.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) You often can resolve problems with a specific piece of hardware by installing an HWE kernel as updated firmware typically provides improves support for some hardware. Whether your particular issue will be solved in the nest point release remains to be seen. Unfortunately I am unable to tell the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the package by searching on launchpad.  [Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/4.13.0-1017.18) is the entry for the version referenced in that bug report.

To see the packages's full history look in the [changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+changelog).

In this particular case it looks like that fix was incorporated a long time ago.

But, you probably don't have the linux-oem kernel.  Unless you did something unusual, you probably have the linux-generic kernel.